# Would DriverKit work for custom USB device to control mic volume (no stream)?

Tags: macos, usb, hid, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I would like to ask for guidance on how to ideally communicate with a custom USB HID device on MacOS.

**Use case**
Modify a microphone volume via an external USB HID device.

**Question**
Can I use DriverKit (HIDDriverKit) for that or I need to use IOKit? I have read something here about audio limitation, but not sure what exactly is not supported.

> DriverKit doesn’t support USB devices that manipulate audio or that
> communicate wirelessly over Bluetooth or Wi-Fi. For those types of
> devices, create a kernel extension using IOKit.
> — [Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/creating_a_driver_using_the_driverkit_sdk)

Would DriverKit still work in my case as I am not sending audio streams but controlling volume only?

Many thanks!
Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you wouldn't even need to use DriverKit. (from experience: avoid it if you can!)

You can communicate with HID-compliant devices directly from user space processes. User space processes can generally also control the volume on audio devices.

So by far the easiest option would be to have a launch agent which uses IOKit matching as its launch condition so it starts up when your device is connected. Your agent can communicate with the device using the `IOHIDManager` API to receive events when your buttons are pressed, and then use the regular Core Audio APIs to control volume.

It doesn't have to be a launch agent, incidentally: a regular Cocoa app with a UI can do all of this as well. (And indeed, you may want to show some form of UI as feedback to the user pressing the buttons.)

Comment: Hey Phil! Thanks so much. Actually, I have currently a Cocoa app, and it works great as you mentioned, the issue comes when I bring another window into focus, e.g. switching focus to Safari and it stops listening to the buttons, then I switch back to my app and it works again. It seems like the process is paused or something.

That is why I thought, that the communication with HID device must run somewhere deeper in the background. 

I would like that it works like a mouse or keyboard no matter what app is in the forefront. Do you know some tricks on how to make the connection alive? :-)

Comment: Ah, interesting, I've not come across this issue, it probably depends on the subtype of HID device. Have you tried using the [`kIOHIDOptionsTypeSeizeDevice` option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1556660-anonymous/kiohidoptionstypeseizedevice)? If this doesn't help, you could try to find out what happens if you handle the events in a process running as root. (`sudo`) If that helps, moving the driver aspect to a launch *daemon* should work. (These run as root.)

Comment: I will definitely try these options! The issue is probably because I use the native SDK Mac libraries provided by SiliconLabs (the HID USB bridge producer). The device is HID-compliant so the methods you suggest may work. Thank you for the direction! 